# Asynchronous receiving TCP packets in python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have an instant messaging app, with client written in python.

Code that connects to a server:

```
def connect(self, host, port, name):
    host = str(host)
    port = int(port)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    s.send('CONNECT:' + name)
    print s.recv(1024)

    return s
```

Then s will be stored in a self.socket.

Here is function that receives tcp packets from server and prints it to command line.

```
def chat(self):
    while True:
        data = self.socket.recv(4096)
        if not data:
            pass
        else:
            print data
```

So in my mind it should receive everything server sends and prints out, but it isn't happens. Anyone knows how to bring it to life?

Comment: what exactly does happen when you try running?

Comment: It works, i can send a message to a server and server receives it, but i cant receive messages on a client side.
 Btw it works with a telnet client.

Comment: And before there was
 if not data:
 print 'Error'
And it start to print it infinitely

Comment: I did write a script for TCP chat, in my script the sending and receiving was simultaneous, like it was a loop with `socket.send` and `socket.recv` and it works just fine. Try doing that.

Comment: try editing the `while` loop and adding a `send` before the `recv`.

Comment: If you wanna do an asynchronous chat, try doing it with udp socket.

Comment: Kinda strange, huh? Guess i will receive message only if i will send one?

Comment: K, will try with UDP too, thanks

Comment: If `recv` returns a null string from a TCP socket, that means the connection was closed/aborted. So if you get that, you should be breaking from your `while` loop in that case. (Can't say why the connection was broken without more info.) There is no requirement to send data in order to receive.

Comment: Well guys, i've fixed it, and problem was in my server architecture, heh.
But now a problem to simultaneous sending and recieving. Have no idea how to do it

Comment: I've added an answer, was to big for the comment, check it out.

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve] - you're missing enough code to actually reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way with `select` function to monitor multiple streams, make a list of all the streams you need to handle and use the `select` function for it, for the user input use `sys.stdin` and all the sockets that you expect to chat with.
check this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html
But still the best way to do asynchronous chat will be with `udp`, it will work really fine

Comment: Thank you friend, but problem was in how my server works. Server receives not just a message, as i did, but a message with a command, like SAY or QUIT. All i did is added this command to a TCP packet i send and it works properly now. As asynchronous, i'm not sure that i use this word right, but it works and it's ok, thank you again.

Comment: While OP chose to accept it, this answer is misleading at best. There is *no* requirement in TCP for bidirectional data flow. TCP is perfectly capable of having only one party send data. The socket does not "expect a return message". There are reasons why one would want to use TCP for unidirectional data transfer; UDP is not *always* the right solution for that.

Comment: You are right sir, tcp can have unidirectional transfer. sorry for the mistake. Actually I had the same problem before, and this method quickly solved it, so i posted the same.